# T-SQL Join on columns OR fixed value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out some basic rules in T-SQL.

What I'm trying to achieve here, is to get only the records from Table1 which has a match in Table2 - AND - all records from Table1 where the 'Valid' column has a value of 1 (=true).
Previously I've done this with two selects and a UNION like this:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
UNION
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 T1
WHERE T1.Valid = 1
```

But isn't there any other way than using multiple selects and UNION to achieve this?
While fiddling, I did the following code bit, which however only works if there's exactly one match in Table2 (otherwise it'll multiply the records by the number of matches in T2).

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
    OR T1.Valid = 1
```

What would be the best way to achieve my goal in terms of performance?

Also please don't hold back on the comments, possible flaws, or explanations of how and why another solution might be better.

Comment: The "or T1.Valid = 1" looks a bit strange to me, I would do INNER JOIN Table2 T2 on T1.Id = T2.ID and then on the next line I would put WHERE T1.Valid = 1

Comment: Since you don't actually want any records from `Table2` I would be inclined to change your `JOIN` to `EXISTS` - `SELECT T1.* FROM Table1 T1 WHERE T1.Valid = 1 OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 T2 WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID);` I think the execution plan would be the same, but (in my opinion) this displays the intent more clearly.

Comment: Using ´WHERE T1.Valid = 1´ would return no records, since I'm using inner join GuidoG

Answer (score -1, accepted):

assuming that `T1.ID` and `T2.ID` is unique or a primary key:

If there are duplicates you may have to write `SELECT DISTINCT T1.*`. The `UNION` operator in the orinal selects only distinct values.

this one should do:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 T1
WHERE T1.ID IN ( SELECT T2.ID FROM Table2 T2 WHERE T2.ID IS NOT NULL)
   OR T1.Valid = 1
```

or

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T2.ID IS NOT NULL OR T1.Valid = 1
```

but i think, the execution plan will be the same at the end.

Comment: Probably not equal execution plans nor results if there exists multiple rows in Table2 for an Id in Table1?

Comment: @larsts the `IN` willnot care if there duplicates or not. the first result would be different if the rows in T1 are not distinct, the second would introduce duplicate rows if T2 were not unique

Comment: Using LEFT JOIN and disregarding entries where T2.ID is Null is a good and understandable solution! Thanks :)